# A probability puzzle

Tags: probability

There are many people in the world, and each person participates in a subset of some finite list of hobbies.  Some pairs of people are friends.  The following rules apply:

(1) If two people are friends, then they share exactly one hobby.

(2) For any hobby $h$, given that two people share $h$, the probability that they are friends is $k$.

(3) Hobby-based friendship is transitive.  That is: for any hobby $h$, if Bob and Joe are friends and share hobby $h$, and Joe and Fred are friends and share hobby $h$, then Bob and Fred are friends (and share hobby $h$).

Prove or disprove: the probability that two people are friends is at most $k$.

Comment: Note that the probability that two people are friends is the probability that they are friends given they share a hobby times the probability that two people share a hobby.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Thanks for the hint.  I'm having trouble turning it into a proof, though.  I know $\Pr(\text{friends} \, | \, \text{share } h_k)$, but it seems that I need to know $\Pr(\text{friends} \, | \, \text{share } h_k \text{ but not } h_{j < k})$ to get an answer.